# Tomcat not getting data from TCP recv-Q, hanging

Tags: linux, tomcat, tcp

I have a program which is essentially a tomcat server with postgreSQL DB running on CentOS Linux 6.3.  When a client submits a larger amount of data (~10MB) to the server, which should be received on TCP 9090, the client seems to hang and not get a response from the server.  I saw nothing significant in the logs, all I could find was that the connection existed on port 9090 and that there was about 3.5 MB sitting in the recv-Q in netstat's output.  Is this likely a system or application issue?

This is what strace  shows:
`9089  futex(0x7fdd80862528, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
9089  futex(0x7fdd81e145a4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, {1374870092, 226655000}, ffffffff <unfinished ...>
9085  <... futex resumed> )             = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
9085  futex(0x7fdd88004728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
9085  futex(0x7fdd94013464, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, {1374870092, 226812000}, ffffffff <unfinished ...>
9071  <... futex resumed> )             = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
9071  futex(0x7fde00092c28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
9071  futex(0x40b62e64, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, {1374870087, 319631000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
9071  futex(0x7fde00092c28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
9071  futex(0x40b62e64, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, {1374870087, 369779000}, ffffffff`

Comment: If you strace the receiving process while the recv-q is in that state, what's it doing?

Comment: futex(0x7f6e3e41f9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 6231, NULL

Comment: Reading on futex(2) it seems like that it is waiting for the value at that memory location to change, but perhaps it never does.  PID 6231 does not yet exist in the process table. The PID of the original process is 6230.

Comment: The futex syscall is the only one that got made before the TCP connection was terminated (I am still not sure what terminated the connection, but it was server side I am pretty sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a low memory issue for the java process.  Adding RAM and tuning the DB resolved it.  Java memory issues?  Shocking, huh?